# R - How to create a table comparing results of two different methods

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Sample  AlgoA   AlgoB
A001    R1  R1
A002    R2  R3
A003    R1  R1
A004    R3  R2
A005    R1  R1
A006    R2  R2
A007    R1  R3
A008    R3  R3
```

I want to summarize this table with the counts of each combination of results. For example, x samples had AlgoA and AlgoB give R1 as the value, y samples had AlgoA value R1 and AlgoB value R2, z samples had AlgoA Value R1 and AlgoB value R3, etc for each combination possible (9 combos)

I'm unsure what this type of table is even called, So far I've only been able to get individual counts, ie x samples are R1, y are R2, z are R3, but unable to combine both together as described above.

This is the final table I'm looking for:

[image: Table of Results]

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with(df, table(AlgoA, AlgoB))
#      AlgoB
# AlgoA R1 R2 R3
#    R1  3  0  1
#    R2  0  1  1
#    R3  0  1  1
```

Using this data:

```
df = read.table(text = 'Sample  AlgoA   AlgoB
A001    R1  R1
A002    R2  R3
A003    R1  R1
A004    R3  R2
A005    R1  R1
A006    R2  R2
A007    R1  R3
A008    R3  R3', header = T)
```